# Updating linked/unified contacts with Contacts library fails

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact, cncontactstore

Issues with updating linked contact using Contacts library swift.

I am trying to update a contact in my contact list in my application. This contact is linked with another contact in the contact list built in on the phone. So when I try to update the contact it fails with error message: "CNErrorDomain-code 2".

If the contact is not linked it works fine, its only with linked/unified contacts.

This is what I get in the console:

```
Error Domain=CNErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={CNKeyPaths=(
    phoneNumbers
)}
```

The same happonds with emailAdresses.

Does anyone know about this error or can guide me in the right direction? I have searched google and stack, could not find anything.

I can gladly post more code if that is necessary! I am desperate to solve this issue.

Comment: Found any solution to this one?

Comment: No, unfortunately not! So this topic is still very much relevant.